# Graphs with no simplicial vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph, we say that a vertex $v$ is simplicial if its neighborhood is a clique. Are there any known structure theorems that describe all graphs without any simplicial vertices? If these graphs have been studied before, would you happen to know of any references?

Comment: Probably not, because that sounds like a weird property to consider. For example attaching a pendant edge creates a simplicial vertex. Most graphs satisfy your property. It does not look like it gives implies any particularly interesting structure.

Comment: All such graphs are non-[chordal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph).